# overlay div with zoom without move below elements

Tags: html, css

I need help to overlay the div that contains the zoom of the image without move the bar which contains the thumbs of the images.

One of the things that I tried was playing with the z-index in all the divs but i can't make it work. Then i tried by change the width and height of the container div of the zoom, but rhe result was that the bar of the thumbs in the bottom move down consequence of the change of the height of the container.

Here's the example of each of my tries

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/KU6NU/22/ <--- here's the zoom doesn't appear completely 

 http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/KU6NU/20/ <--- here's the bottom elements move
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't understand what you mean, can you write more specific?

I just can give you a suggestion:
1. you must check the overlay div contain the thumbs image correctly, not out of div overlay.
2. if the div not accommodate the thumbs, you can give css code(overflow:hidden) in div overlay.
3. to make your thumb appear in top of the div overlay, you can put z-index:9999 in thumbs div, and set the z-index for overlay div smaller than thumbs div.

is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi and thanks for asking ok, I rephrase my question but you should move this answer into a comment.